# Rails: How do I transactionally add a has_many association to an existing model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many, belongs-to

Let's imagine I run an imaginary art store with a couple models (and by models I'm referring to the Rails term not the arts term as in nude models) that looks something like this:

```
class Artwork < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchase
  belongs_to :artist
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artworks
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

The `Artwork` is created and sometime later it is included in a `Purchase`. In my `create` or `update` controller method for `Purchase` I would like to associate the new `Purchase` with the existing `Artwork`.

If the `Artwork` did not exist I could do `@purchase.artworks.build` or `@purchase.artworks.create`, but these both assume that I'm creating a new `Artwork` which I am not. I could add the existing artwork with something like this:

```
params[:artwork_ids].each do |artwork|
  @purchase.artworks << Artwork.find(artwork)
end
```

However, this isn't transactional. The database is updated immediately. (Unless of course I'm in the `create` controller in which case I think it may be done "transactionally" since the `@purchase` doesn't exist until I call `save`, but that doesn't help me for `update`.) There is also the `@purchase.artwork_ids=` method, but that is immediate as well.

I think something like this will work for the `update` action, but it is very inelegant.

```
@purchase = Purchase.find(params[:id])
result = @purchase.transaction do
  @purchase.update_attributes(params[:purchase])
  params[:artwork_ids].each do |artwork|
    artwork.purchase = @purchase
    artwork.save!
  end
end
```

This would be followed by the conventional:

```
if result 
  redirect_to purchase_url(@purchase), notice: 'Purchase was successfully updated.' }
else
  render action: "edit"
end
```

What I'm looking for is something like the way it would work from the other direction where I could just put `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in my model and then call `result = @artwork.save` and everything works like magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a way to do what I want which fairly elegant. I needed to make updates to each part of my `Product` MVC.

Model:

```
attr_accessible: artwork_ids
```

I had to add artwork_ids to attr_accessible since it wasn't included before.

View:

```
= check_box_tag "purchase[artwork_ids][]", artwork.id, artwork.purchase == @purchase
```

In my view I have an array for each artwork with a `check_box_tag`. I couldn't use `check_box` because of the gotcha where not checking the box would cause a hidden value of "true" to be sent instead of an artwork id. However, this leaves me with the problem of deleting all the artwork from a purchase. When doing `update`, if I uncheck each check box, then the `params[:purchase]` hash won't have an `:artwork_ids` entry.

Controller:

```
params[:purchase][:artwork_ids] ||= []
```

Adding this guarantees that the value is set, and will have the desired effect of removing all existing associations. However, this causes a pesky rspec failure
`Purchase.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({'these' => 'params'})` fails because `:update_attributes` actually received `{"these"=>"params", "artwork_ids"=>[]})`. I tried setting a `hidden_value_tag` in the view instead, but couldn't get it to work. I think this nit is worthy of a new question.

Comment: On second thought `= hidden_field_tag "purchase[artwork_ids][]"` seems to work.

Comment: I just realized that this is basically Railscast 17. I'm pretty sure I've even watched it before, but I think I forgot about it because it was using HABTM.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to use make the purchase model a join table and have many to many associations.

Here is an example for your use case.

Customer model

```
    has_many :purchases

    has_many :artwork, :through => :purchase
```

Artwork model

```
    has_many :purchases

    has_many :customers, :through => :purchase
```

Purchase model

```
    belongs_to :customer
    belongs_to :artwork
```

The purchase model should contain customer_id and artwork_id.

you would also need to create a purchase controller that allows you create a new purchase object.

When a customer presses the purchase button it would create a new purchase object which includes the customer_id and the artwork_id. This allows you to create an association between the customer and the artwork they purchase. You can also have a price_paid column to save the price the customer paid at the time of purchase.

if you need more help you can research join many to many associations using :through.

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I really need the purchase to include several different pieces of artwork which means I need `Purchase` to be `has_many`.

Comment: well you can use a cart gem but if you want to do it from scratch. i would do a cart model where you can add multiple artwork to the cart then when the customer actually buys the items in the cart you can associate the order to the customer and show multiple artworks